Is using こ　子 as a noun suffix a calque from chinese?
I was wondering if こ was used as a noun suffix before the contact with chinese (振子 etc) or its a calque.

I do not know specifically about ふりこ (振り子 or 振子) or Sino-Japanese 振子{しんし} or Mandarin [振子]{zhènzǐ}, and which of them was created first, but suffix */-kʷo/ is attested in Old Japanese for diminutive meaning and endearment meaning for nouns referring to humans or fish (according to Alexander Vovin (2020, page 212)).

Noun ふりこ was maybe created in 19th century (this page has quote from 1888), and could even be attempt of calque from Neo-Latin pendulum. In Latin, suffix -ulus is often used to create diminutives, but for pendulus, meaning "agent noun or adjective from a verb" of that suffix is relevant.

Japan's contact with Chinese dates back to around the 3rd century, when Japan is still in the Yayoi period, so I don't think complex words like 振り子 existed before this contact. However, for this specific word, I don't know whether it was borrowed from Chinese or independently invented in Japanese. The answer to whether こ is an old suffix is probably "yes". The word 猫 (cat) is thought to have originated from 子 (child).
However, if you are thinking about 子 meaning "particle; -let" in scientific terms, such as 分子 (molecule), 原子 (atom), 電子 (electron), 光子 (photon) and 振動子 (oscillator), at least some of them were actually created in Japan first during the 19th century, and later imported back to China. Please refer to wasei-kango. Note that these instances of 子 are pronounced as し, not こ.
